# What would prevent records from being added to a Full Text index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I had a problem where I was getting no results back from a full text search for a record that I know was there. Dropping the index and recreating it fixed the problem, which makes me think that the record wasn't added to the index. What would cause that?

This is on our QA environment and we occasionally restore this environment from a production backup. Could that have caused this? *Edit* I just ran the same query on production and the full text index returned the correct result there, so I'm not sure that the restore from production would be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I would say the most likely reason that the new records had not been added is based on the configuration of how the fulltext index populates. In SQL Server 2008 R2, the fulltext index updates based on a scheduled job, not dynamically on insert/update as other indexes do. Questions to check:

- What type of population is configured for the index? (See [Full Text Index Population](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142575(v=sql.105).aspx) and [sys.dm_fts_index_population (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186897(v=sql.105).aspx) for more information)
- Is there a schedule for performing the population? Should there be one?

  - If there is a schedule, is it disabled? When is it scheduled for?
  - If the population is set to Manual, have you triggered the rebuild?

Also, from Books On Line, in the section [CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
CHANGE_TRACKING [ = ] { MANUAL | AUTO | OFF [ , NO POPULATION ] }
Specifies whether changes (updates, deletes or inserts) made to table columns that are 
covered by the full-text index will be propagated by SQL Server to the full-text index. 
Data changes through WRITETEXT and UPDATETEXT are not reflected in the full-text index, 
and are not picked up with change tracking. 


MANUAL 
    Specifies that the tracked changes must be propagated manually by calling the 
    ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX … START UPDATE POPULATION Transact-SQL statement (manual 
    population). You can use SQL Server Agent to call this Transact-SQL statement 
    periodically. 

AUTO
    Specifies that the tracked changes will be propagated automatically as data is 
    modified in the base table (automatic population). Although changes are propagated 
    automatically, these changes might not be reflected immediately in the full-text 
    index. AUTO is the default. 

OFF [ , NO POPULATION] 
    Specifies that SQL Server does not keep a list of changes to the indexed data. When 
    NO POPULATION is not specified, SQL Server populates the index fully after it
    is created.

    The NO POPULATION option can be used only when CHANGE_TRACKING is OFF. When 
    NO POPULATION is specified, SQL Server does not populate an index after it is 
    created. The index is only populated after the user executes the 
    ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX command with the START FULL POPULATION or 
    START INCREMENTAL POPULATION clause.
```

Comment: Thanks! That sounds exactly like what's going on.

Comment: Well, maybe I spoke too soon. The index already had `CHANGE_TRACKING` set to `AUTO`. How do I check if there's a schedule and if it's disabled or not?